# one xml element (with children) to many table rows

Tags: xml, sql-server-2000

I need to turn the following XML structure into the following table structure (in SQL Server 2000)

```
<family>
  <parent>
    <id>1</id>
    <child>test1</child>
    <child>test2</child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <id>2</id>
    <child>test3</child>
    <child>test4</child>
  </parent>
</family>
```

Sample data in table:

```
parent_id child
1         test1
1         test2
2         test3
2         test4
```

Query:

```
SELECT Child FROM 
  OPENXML (@hdoc, 'family/parent/child') 
    WITH(Child nvarchar(256) '.')
```

gives result:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT ParentID, Child FROM 
  OPENXML (@hdoc, 'family/parent') 
    WITH(
      Child nvarchar(256) 'child/.',
      ParentID int 'id/.'
    )
```

gives result:

```
1 test1
2 test3
```

How do I get both parent id and all children?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ParentID, Child FROM 
  OPENXML (@hdoc, 'family/parent/child') 
    WITH(
      Child nvarchar(256) '.',
      ParentID int '../id'
    )
```